# What is the difference between GUI testing of web application and GUI testing of cockpit displays

Tags: web-application

I am familiar with GUI testing for web applications, but now I need to test cockpit displays for avionics systems.

What are the critical differences between web application testing and avionic display systems testing that I need to be careful about? I can't find much information online, and I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Have you started your own list? What do you think the differences are?

Comment: I have edited your question to make it less likely to be close-voted. If I misunderstood what you are looking for you are welcome to revert my edits.

Comment: This not a site were we do your homework, make an effort to answer the question and people will be happy to help, we won't do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Having never done avionics testing, here are my initial thoughts:

1. Do you intend to automate this? What sort of infrastructure and framework will you need to do so?
2. One of the bigger differences is going to be real-time operation. How quickly do the displays respond to their inputs? What happens if two things go wrong at once? Fifteen?
3. What are your inputs and outputs? How independent are they of each other?
4. Remember that most of the time, you'll be using very little of the code behind it (normal flight), but the Very Important Stuff is how emergencies are handled, which is just a fraction of the time, but it has to work.